# GPS coordinates are not stored in my variables

Tags: gps, coordinates

The following code does not seem to use the location data when performing calcCrow in the for loop for all the locations. When I check it using the Chrome Debugger and go step by step the code never actually gets the coordinates until after the code is completed execution.

```
var locationsOfInterest = [];
var currentlat= 0;
var currentlong= 0;
x = navigator.geolocation;
x.getCurrentPosition(getposition);
function getposition(position){

    currentlat = position.coords.latitude;
    currentlong = position.coords.longitude;

};
var sunwayuni = {

    title: "Sunway University",
    latitude: 3.0681,
    longitude: 101.6041,
}

var monashaustralia = {

    title: "Monash Australia",
    latitude: -37.876823,
    longitude: 145.045837,
}

var kualalumpur = {

    title: "Kuala Lumpur",
    latitude: 3.1390,
    longitude: 101.6869,
}
locationsOfInterest= [sunwayuni, monashaustralia, kualalumpur]

for (var i = 0; i < locationsOfInterest.length; i++){

    locationsOfInterest[i].distance = calcCrow(locationsOfInterest[i].latitude, locationsOfInterest[i].longitude);
}

function calcCrow(lat2, lon2) 
    {
      var R = 6371; // km
      var drLat = toRad(lat2-currentlat);
      var drLon = toRad(lon2-currentlong);
      var rlat1 = toRad(currentlat);
      var rlat2 = toRad(lat2);

      var a = Math.sin(drLat/2) * Math.sin(drLat/2) +
        Math.sin(drLon/2) * Math.sin(drLon/2) * Math.cos(rlat1) * Math.cos(rlat2); 
      var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
      var d = R * c;
      return d;
    }

    // Converts numeric degrees to radians
    function toRad(Value) 
    {
        return Value * Math.PI / 180;
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that `getCurrentPosition` is async. If that's the case, all your code needs to be run from the callback you pass to `getCurrentPosition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html5  getcurrentposition functions works asynchronously so all processing do in getcurrentposition  function.

var locationsOfInterest = []; var currentlat= 0; var currentlong= 0; x = navigator.geolocation; x.getCurrentPosition(getposition); function getposition(position){ currentlat = position.coords.latitude; currentlong = position.coords.longitude;

var sunwayuni = { title: "Sunway University", latitude: 3.0681, longitude: 101.6041, } var monashaustralia = { title: "Monash Australia", latitude: -37.876823, longitude: 145.045837, } var kualalumpur = { title: "Kuala Lumpur", latitude: 3.1390, longitude: 101.6869, } locationsOfInterest= [sunwayuni, monashaustralia, kualalumpur] for (var i = 0; i < locationsOfInterest.length; i++){ locationsOfInterest[i].distance = calcCrow(locationsOfInterest[i].latitude, locationsOfInterest[i].longitude); } function calcCrow(lat2, lon2) { var R = 6371; // km var drLat = toRad(lat2-currentlat); var drLon = toRad(lon2-currentlong); var rlat1 = toRad(currentlat); var rlat2 = toRad(lat2); var a = Math.sin(drLat/2) * Math.sin(drLat/2) + Math.sin(drLon/2) * Math.sin(drLon/2) * Math.cos(rlat1) * Math.cos(rlat2); var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); var d = R * c; return d; } // Converts numeric degrees to radians function toRad(Value) { return Value * Math.PI / 180; }
 };

Comment: Thank you this helped and now my code works, however is there any material worth reading for newbie java script coders like myself who need to understand the concepts fully to be able to present the material to someone else. Additionally is there a reason as to why i am unable to try and store the variable of latitude and longitude globally and then using them in another function to calculate distance ? Thank you so much in advance :)